# Android : Unfortunately, app has stopped

Tags: android

I am a beginner with Android, trying to run my first application. But there's an error in the log file and application get terminated by this message "Unfortunately, app has stopped"!

**Here is my java file:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button mClick=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    mClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    //@Override
    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.hi, 3000).show();          

    }
            });
}
}
```

**And the log has these errors:**

```
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792): Process: com.example.test, PID: 792
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-19 18:50:02.200: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  ... 11 more
```

Can you spot the problem?

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)`. That means line 29.

Comment: `mClick.setOnClickListener(...` is probably line 29. mClick is probably `null`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, but I don't know why   mClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {might produce an exception!

Comment: @user3552862 because mClick is null

Comment: But I have defined button1, and here it is its id in R class: public static final class id {

        public static final int button1=0x7f05003e;

Comment: if `mClick` is indeed null, this means that a `button` with an `id` of `button1` does not exist in the layout `activity_main.xml`

Comment: Yeah, great! thanks. I was just confusing activity-main.xml with fragment_main.xml, do you know what are the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mClick button is not being created, probably because findViewById(R.id.button1) is failing.

Then, because the button is null, when you call a function on it you get a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

mClick is probably null. 
Check if R.id.button1 exists in the layout you set on setContentView.